# Why double consonant words differ between English and French?

Tags: orthographe, linguistique, comparaison-de-langues

I make many mistakes when writing double consonant words both in French (my mother tongue) and in English.
One of the main difficulties is that very similar words do not follow the same rule for the doubling of the consonant.
For example (French vs English):

- adresse vs a**dd**ress
- asymétrie vs asy**mm**etry
- li**tt**érature vs literature

Is there a reason for that?

Do you have any tips to avoid mistakes?

Comment: +1, but shouldn't that be a candidate for migration to EL&U? From these 3 examples, it looks to me that French is just following the latin root of the word (doubling the consonant if the latin root has it doubled too), and English differing from it...

Comment: Or maybe linguistics.SE?

Comment: Les trois mots ont des évolutions historiques différentes vérifiables sur le [TFL](http://www.cnrtl.fr), symétrie et littérature viennent chacun du latin *symmetria* et a perdu le doublement de la consonne au passage, littérature vient du latin *litteratura* et a gardé les deux consonnes, quand à adresse, dans le sens "postal" il n'est apparu qu'au 12e siècle déverbal de *drecier* lui-même apparu au 12e siècle et issu du latin populaire *directus* (mettre droit). La question telle qu'elle est posée mériterait trois réponses séparées en ce qui concerne le français.

Comment: Pour éviter les erreurs il suffit d'apprendre l'orthographe des mots difficiles par cœur, le français comme l'anglais sont des langues dont les graphies respectives ne suivent dans beaucoup de cas ni la prononciation ni l’étymologie. L'imprégnation par la lecture aide aussi à fixer l'orthographe.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a comparison between English and French and not just the French language. You should check if it is valid for linguistics.SE (depending on what you want, it could be classified as too broad there).